# How to obtain app geolocation 24/7 even with app totally closed

Tags: ios, react-native, ionic-framework, geolocation, location

We want to create an app based in points in a map. The points was saved in a database (or we can save it also in the device) and what we want is send a notification if the user is near from certain point even if the app is open, in background or totally closed.

Do you know if it's posible?

AFAIK Pokemon go, Find my iPhone always are listening our location.

How can I do that?

Thaaanks a lot!! ❤️

Honestly I was try to use https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation and I don't know how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [capacitor-background-geolocation](https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/capacitor-background-geolocation) plugin specifically made to do for what your asking.

Answer (score -1):

There are two concepts that may be appropriate for your need. Geofencing and Significant location change.

Apple created several ways for your app to be opened in background. But any of these should be used responsively or your app will be terminated or even rejected when reviewing.

Check how you can enable background mode and handle location changes described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/handling_location_updates_in_the_background).
You can find some stuff about geofencing [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions).
And about significant location change [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati).

So the geofencing concepts is cool because you can add regions to be monitored and you can track if user entered a certain region or exited it. But the downside is that there is a pretty low limit on how many locations you can monitor at a time.

Significant location change is not as smart but will trigger when user is moving around. Significantly.

For a more specific answer you should probably ask more specific question. But to begin with I suggest that you try and play with these tools.